# Hide arrow in standard dropdown?

Tags: html, css, listbox

Is there a a way to hide the arrow in a standard dropdown select fieldset?

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/HwSTm/)

I have an autocomplete system where you fill in the organisation number of a company and it finds the info based on a database. I'd like to have the select box, but without the arrow..

I need it to do this as it's a double function form, either you can fill in your ORG nr or just manually type it in, pretty simple, probably used all over the internet.

Thanks :)

Comment: Why can't you use a standard text field?

Comment: Because it needs to be a select box, just without that arrow :)

Comment: Din't understand it well. Do you have a textbox with autocomplete, and based on the value in this textbox, you need to select something in dropdown automatically? Why can't you use another textbox for that?

Comment: Some info returns wrong, like the registered country might be Sweden but it'll return Denmark, so in this case it needs to be a seslct box to correct the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kyle,
Usually autocomplete systems use input text elements instead of a select element. This creates what you are trying to achieve. Google is a classic example of this.

If you want, you can take a look at jQuery's autocomplete plugin to get another example and some code ideas, or whatever. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete

Comment: Thanks, I've just realised I forgot to add a really important part of info as to why I need this. Will update question.

Comment: There is still a way you can do both selection ("fill in") and insertion ("manual insertion") with a text field and jQuery's autocomplete. you gotta just configure it the right way :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy, but you can fake it by putting a button above a Select that has its size property set to a value greater than 0.

Have the Select hidden and positioned absolutely under the button. Clicking the button shows the list. Selecting the list changes the text on the button and re-hides the Select.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant ! I have made a <span> position:absolute and put it over that arrow and BAM! it's hidden :D

Answer (score 1):

This way you need a text box, because you cannot type anything in <select> tag.
And put an onclick event to this box to open autocomplete with all possible values.